# "Save as" in IPython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to save a file with a different name, and keep the file with the old name (ie, no renaming) in Ipython Notebook.

Is there a standard "save as" feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not yet, we need to refactor the saving/renaming API.

I woudl suggest "open a copy" as a workaround, where the copy would be the "oldest" notebook.

Comment: Thanks. If you're part of the IPython dev team by the way, thanks a bunch, it's why I switched to python.